# url with question mark considered as new http request?

Tags: url, caching, browser, httprequest, browser-cache

I am optimization my web page by implementing caching, so if I want the browser not to take data from cache, then I will append a dynamic number as query value.

eg: **google.com?val=823746**

But some time, if I want to bring data from cache for the below url, the browser is making a new http request to server, its not taking data from cache. Is that because of the question mark in URL ?

**eg:** http://google.com**?**

Please provide some reference document link.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Navin

Answer (score 1):

Use appropriate HTTP headers.
Search of `pragma: no-cache` and `Expires`

Browsers may not cache URLs that contain a query string (part after `?` ) unless the headers indicate the expiry time explicitly.

Cache policy is not same across all browsers. If you don't specify appropriate headers the results may be even more unpredictable.

Since query strings are used with dynamically generated pages, the browser may take that hint and fire a new request even if the query string is same.
For example, a desktop browser may err on side of caution and fire a new request. On the other hand a mobile browser with aggressive cache policy may pull the page from cache.

Comment: thank you for the reply, my concern is just with the question mark, not the strings after that. So main scenario is the url without have any query value but the url has ? mark. And yes the HTTP header is fine

Comment: Well actually presence of ? alone can be taken as presence of an empty query string.